# Why module created for LoaderDependency must have _source property?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-loader

I'm trying to develop loader. I follow https://survivejs.com/webpack/extending/loaders/! with documentation of webpack [https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/]("Writing webpack loader)!.

I'm getting following error ['Error: The module created for a LoaderDependency must have a property _source'](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/87a3046eb74f8825e08866fde3e39930ec6ebb0a/lib/dependencies/LoaderPlugin.js#L84)!.

This happens when I'm calling `this.loadModule`. Passed param as the first argument represents the path to the node_modules package.

What does this error exactly mean?